# My Spring application is generating a ClassCastException

Tags: json, spring

I am getting a `ClassCastException` when I try to get class items 
from the following list iterator. The web application is running on TC7, 
Win OS

```
List<CustomerList> aaData = customerlistDao.getCustomerList();
```

putting data in a JSON form that DataTables recognizes

```
Iterator<CustomerList> itr = aaData.iterator();

cl = itr.next();
```

Comment: Just to be thorough, what is the type of `cl`?

Comment: `getCustomerList` returns a `List<CustomerList>`? Not a `List<Customer>`?

Comment: You should post the stacktrace. It usually provides the answer.